# Getting of website image from the url

Tags: php, curl

I tried using `Snappy` (src - http://www.codediesel.com/downloads/snappy) and `wkhtmltoimage` (src - http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopd) on Windows 7 to get the images from URL but every time I get

> error: The image cannot be display as it contains errors

**Code:**

```
<?php
require_once('Snappy/Media.php');
require_once('Snappy/Image.php');

/* 'wkhtmltoimage' executable  is located in the current directory */
$snap = new Image('C://"Program Files"/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe');

/* Displays the bbc.com website index page screen-shot in the browser */
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$snap->output('http://www.bbc.com bbc.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: Run the code without the image/jpeg header("Content-Type: ..") set in, and see if you get any sensible error messages in your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are using, but http://www.artviper.net/website-tools/website-thumbnails.php has a nice site. You can even simply customize their link to show any website. It takes a while to load though. So I would advise to save them locally

You can even customize the output width and the browser width/height.

Simple sample code to save them locally and show image:

```
<?php
$site = $_POST['site'];
if (strlen($site)==0)
  $site = "www.stackoverflow.com";

$url = "http://85.25.9.83/artviper.php?w=360&sdx=1024&q=90&userID=AV_47845683_352324_2FC&url=".urlencode($site);
$content = implode('', file($url));
file_put_contents("myimage.jpg", $content);
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name='site' value='<?php echo $site; ?>'/>
<input type="submit" value="Show image" />
</form>

<img src='myimage.jpg' />
```